# How do I add different classes to <td> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Hey I have two `td` elements in a table.

I want the have separate style classes for them. How do I do this?

This is my code:

```js
table += "<tr>";
  for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
    table += "<td>" + "<table>" + "<td>" + value1 "</td>" + "<td>" + value2 + "</td>" + "</table>";
  }
table += "</tr>";
```

I have tried to simply add class in `td` element but that does not work.

Any ideas? I use Javascript to create the table.

So this does not work:

```js
table += "<tr>";
  for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
    table += "<td>" + "<table>" + "<td class="one">" + value1 "</td>" + "<td class="two">" + value2 + "</td>" + "</table>";
  }
table += "</tr>";
```

Comment: You need to escape your double quotes with a backslash. Example: ` "<td class=\"one\">" `

Comment: In addition to @ChiragRavindra you can also change the double quotes around `one` to single quotes.

Comment: `"<table>" + "<td …` is invalid. A TD can't be a direct child of a TABLE. There will be error correction occurring that will build a DOM that is likely different to what you expect.

Comment: Just like @RobG said, I think there must be a `"<tr>"` between `"<table>"` and `"<td>"` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using single quotes inside double-quoted strings, like this

```
table += "<tr>";
  for(var i = 0; i < data.list.length; i++){
    table += "<td>" + "<table>" + "<td class='one'>" + value1 "</td>" + "<td class='two'>" + value2 + "</td>" + "</table>";
  }
table += "</tr>";
```